# Hex to Byte Array in C# and Java Gives Different Results

Tags: c#, java, hex, byte, arrays

First of all, sorry for the long post, I want to include all my thoughts so it's easier for you guys to find what's wrong about my code.

I want to transfer an Hex string from a C# application to a Java application. But, when I convert the same Hex value to a Byte Array on both languages, the output is different.

For instance, the same Hex value gives

```
  [101, 247, 11, 173, 46, 74, 56, 137, 185, 38, 40, 191, 204, 104, 83, 154]
```

in C# and

```
  [101, -9, 11, -83, 46, 74, 56, -119, -71, 38, 40, -65, -52, 104, 83, -102]
```

in Java

Here are the methods I use in C#:

```
public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] byteArray)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(byteArray).Replace("-",""); //To convert the whole array
}

public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{

    byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++)
    {
        string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
        HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    return HexAsBytes;
}
```

And the ones in Java:

```
 public static String ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for (byte b: bytes) {
     builder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
     }
     return builder.toString().toUpperCase();
 }

 public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here's an example in C#:

```
        String hexString = "65F70BAD2E4A3889B92628BFCC68539A";
        byte[] byteArray = HexBytes.HexStringToByteArray(hexString);
        //Using the debugger, byteArray = [101, 247, 11, 173, 46, 74, 56, 137, 185, 38, 40, 191, 204, 104, 83, 154]
        String hexString2 = HexBytes.ByteArrayToHexString(byteArray)
        Console.Write("HEX: " + hexString2);
        //Outputs 65F70BAD2E4A3889B92628BFCC68539A
```

And an example in Java:

```
    String hexString = "65F70BAD2E4A3889B92628BFCC68539A";
    byte[] byteArray = HexBytes.HexStringToByteArray(hexString);
    //Using the debugger, byteArray = [101, -9, 11, -83, 46, 74, 56, -119, -71, 38, 40, -65, -52, 104, 83, -102]
    String hexString2 = HexBytes.ByteArrayToHexString(byteArray);
    System.out.println("HEX: " + hexString2);
    //Outputs 65F70BAD2E4A3889B92628BFCC68539A
```

As you can see, when I do the opposite operation, the final Hex value is equal to the first one, which means the way I convert is potentially good in both languages individually. But I don't understand why the conversion from Hex to a byte array is different in both languages. I thought Hexadecimal was simply a number on another base.

Thanks for the help

Cydrick

**Update**

I fixed this issue by replacing the C# code with the following code:

```
public static string ByteArrayToHexString(sbyte[] byteArray)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(convert(byteArray)).Replace("-", ""); //To convert the whole array
}

public static sbyte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{

    byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++)
    {
        string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
        HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    return convert(HexAsBytes);
}


private static sbyte[] convert(byte[] byteArray)
{
    sbyte[] sbyteArray = new sbyte[byteArray.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sbyteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        sbyteArray[i] = unchecked((sbyte) byteArray[i]);
    }

    return sbyteArray;
}

private static byte[] convert(sbyte[] sbyteArray)
{
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[sbyteArray.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
    {
        byteArray[i] = (byte) sbyteArray[i];
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, the little known class [SoapHexBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.metadata.w3cxsd2001.soaphexbinary.aspx) is one of the easiest and [fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/624379/80274) ways to get string to hex and and back in the format you showed in your example. The class has been in the .NET framework seance 1.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But, when I convert the same Hex value to a Byte Array on both languages, the output is different.

All you're seeing is that bytes are signed in Java and unsigned in C#. So if you add 256 to any negative value in Java, you'll get the value shown in C#. The actual *bits* in the values are the same - it's just a matter of whether the top bit is treated as a sign bit or not.

EDIT: As noted in comments, if you're ever using the byte as an integer outside the debugger output, you can always use:

```
int someInt = someByte & 0xff;
```

to get the unsigned value.

Comment: In Java, rather than adding 256 to any negative byte value, one can obtain an `int` equal to the unsigned value of the bits stored in any byte value `b` with `(b & 0xff)`.

Comment: @TedHopp: Indeed. But with the debugger output that doesn't help. Will add a note though.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated my question with the answer. I changed from byte[] to sbyte[] in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a debugger issue only. Those negative values you're seeing in the Java debugger are the signed equivalents to the unsigned values you're seeing in the C# debugger. For example, signed byte -9 == unsigned byte 247 (notice that they always differ by 256). The data is fine.