# Convert Hex To Byte Array in Java gives different results from C#.NET [port from C# to Java]

Tags: java, c#, hex, byte

I am trying to convert a small piece of code to Java from C#. [I think don't have to say I'm a noob. :P]

The two codes below returns differently I don't understand why. Thanks for any help.

P.S.: I've checked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922747/hex-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp-and-java-gives-different-results) but the answer doesn't fix my problem.

### C#.NET

```
public class Test
{
    private static sbyte[] HexToByte(string hex)
        {
            if (hex.Length % 2 == 1)
                throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

            sbyte[] arr = new sbyte[hex.Length >> 1];
            int l = hex.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < (l >> 1); ++i)
            {
                arr[i] = (sbyte)((GetHexVal(hex[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hex[(i << 1) + 1])));
            }

            return arr;
        }

        private static int GetHexVal(char hex)
        {
            int val = (int)hex;
            return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
        }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(HexToByte("EE")[0]);
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT: -18

### JAVA

```
class Test
{
    private static int GetHexVal(char hex)
    {
        int val = (int)hex;
        return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
    }

    private static byte[] HexToByte(String hex) throws Exception {
        if (hex.length() % 2 == 1)
            throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

        byte[] arr = new byte[hex.length() >> 1];
        int l = hex.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < (l >> 1); ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal((char)(hex.charAt(i << 1) << 4)) + (GetHexVal(hex.charAt((i << 1) + 1)))));
        }

        return arr;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println((HexToByte("EE")[0]));
    }
}
```

> OUTPUT: 39

I don't understand why this happens and what is the way to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your bracketing for the first character in the Java code. Here's your code:

```
GetHexVal((char)(hex.charAt(i << 1) << 4))
```

That's getting the character, *shifting that*, then calling `GetHexVal`. You want to shift the *result* instead:

```
// Unnecessary cast removed
GetHexVal(hex.charAt(i << 1)) << 4
```

This would have been much easier to see if you'd made your code simpler. I would have written it as:

```
private static byte[] HexToByte(String hex) {
    if (hex.length() % 2 == 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }

    byte[] arr = new byte[hex.length() / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2)
    {
        int highNybble = parseHex(hex.charAt(i));
        int lowNybble = parseHex(hex.charAt(i + 1));
        arr[i / 2] = (byte) ((highNybble << 4) + lowNybble);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

While bitshifting is all very efficient, it's not nearly as *readable* as simply dividing by two... and splitting code up across multiple statements makes it much easier to read each individual part of it.

(I would probably implement `parseHex` with a switch statement, throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` for non-hex digits too...)